# How do i save a javascript variable to my form type in Symfony

Tags: php, javascript, symfony, twig

I have this Javascript variable I want to use in my Form Type

```
// Layout.html.twig    
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
          $('#checkout').click(function(){
               var sold = $("td[title='count"+id+"']").html();
          });
    });
</script>
```

My CheckoutType:

```
//CheckoutType.php

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('orderdate', 'datetime');
    $builder->add('comments', 'hidden', array(
        'data' => $sold
    ));
}
```

Is there anyway I can manage to get the javascript variable as data?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your objective you can

Save it with local storage for newer browsers.

Pass it through URL

Write into a data base with AJAX. insert and update corresppponding information once every few seconds (but this is taxing on the server)

=]